# Rescaling convolution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

I'm trying to numerically calculate multiple convolutions in Matlab and rescaling the result. Because I'm doing discrete convolutions using Matlab's `conv`, I need to divide the convolution by the number of timesteps taken, `N`:

```
N = 1e3;
% N = 1e5;
t = linspace(-10,10,N);

x = t.*exp(-t.^2);
y = exp(-4*t.^2).*cos(t);
z = (t-2)./((t-2).^2+3^2);
w = exp(-3*t.^2).*exp(2i*t);

u = conv(x,y,'same')/N;
% u = conv(conv(conv(x,y,'same')/N,z,'same')/N,w,'same')/N;

plot(t,u)
```

- My result `u` appears to be correctly scaled when there's one convolution (I tested with `N=1e3` and `N=1e5` timesteps) -- but when I try to do more than one convolution, the `N` scaling doesn't seem to be right.
- If I change the `t` range to `linspace(-20,20,N)`, the height of `u` also appears to change.

What am I doing wrong and how do I correctly normalize this resultant `u`?

**Edit:** If we normalise one of the functions like `u = conv(conv(conv(x,y/sum(y),'same'),z/sum(z),'same'),w/sum(w),'same');` this solves the problem from varying the number of timesteps `N`. (But I'm not sure if this mathematically valid.)

Comment: Your z is only a scalar. Is this intended? With `z = (t-2)./((t-2).^2+3^2);` the convolution looks more reasonable.

Comment: You're right - it's been amended.